# What proportion of 27k should both individuals pay?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have 2 individuals one making 177 the other making 415, what percentage of 27 should each pay to make it proportional to their incomes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In total they are making 177 + 415 = 592

So one should pay 177/592 of the total (30%, or 8.10), and the other 415/592 (70%, 18.90).

Answer (score 0):

The first person pays
$$
\frac{177}{177 + 415} \times 27 .
$$